# jquery/javascript perform function on checkbox click or adjacent text click

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an unordered list of text items with checkboxes beside each of them. I want to perform the same function both when a checkbox is checked/unchecked and when the text is clicked.

Here's what I have right now:

**The HTML**

```
<li><input type="checkbox" class="cbox" name="adwords_list[]" value="shave club" ><p class="term"> shave club</p></li>
```

**The JS**

```
$(function() {
    $('ol.phrases li .term').click(function() {
        $cboxStatus = $(this).parent().find('.cbox').prop('checked');

        if ($cboxStatus) {
            $(this).parent().find('.cbox').prop('checked', false);
        } else {
            $(this).parent().find('.cbox').prop('checked', true);
        }
    });
});

$(':checkbox, .term').on('change', function() {
    console.log($(this).prop('checked'));
});
```

The `on.change` function isn't calling when the term is clicked. What can I do to get an accurate representation of the checked state no matter what element is clicked/changed?

Comment: If the adjacent text was a label that targeted the input, you wouldn't need to bind a click event. `<li><label><input type="checkbox" class="cbox" name="adwords_list[]" value="shave club" > shave club</label></li>`

Comment: Use a `label` instead of that `p`. If you successfully pair it with the `input`, it will actually change the checkbox.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you change the `p.term` elements to `label`, with appropriate `for` attributes matching the associated checkboxes, clicking the text is just the same as checking the box.  You then only need to watch the checkbox events.

```
<input type="checkbox" class="cbox" name="adwords_list[]" value="shave club" id="cb1" />  
<label class="term" for="cb1"> shave club</label>
```

You can add

```
.term {
  display: block;
}
```

etc. to your CSS if you need to match the styling of the `p` tag.

Comment: Ugh. Thanks to everyone. That was an utter web development 101 fail.